# Why is PadLeft not working?

Tags: .net, string, padding

I have the following code:

```
string foo = "blah".PadLeft(4, ' ');
```

But when I check it, instead of foo being `"____blah"` (with 4 spaces at the start), it's just `"blah"`. Why doesn't PadLeft do what I expect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the [first argument is total length of resulting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) and not number of character to pad. So in your example you want to use 8 instead of 4.

Comment: @RCIX: It is quite smart behavior, since the most common use for pad is to create a fix length string and then it is very simple to use, no need to calculate the length yourself.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: Thanks, couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `PadLeft` specifies the *total* resulting length you want. Since "blah" starts out four characters long, no padding is added when you specify a length of four. If you want to insert four spaces, change your call to `string foo = "blah".PadLft(8, ' ');` Since the default padding character is a space, you can skip specifying that and just use `string foo = "blah".PadLeft(8)`