# PadLeft doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to add a character many times before a string. AMAIK in C#, it's PadLeft.

```
string firstName = "Mary";
firstName = firstName.PadLeft(3, '*'); // This should return ***Mary
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is PadLeft not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581416/why-is-padleft-not-working)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first argument is total length of the returned string, as "Mary" is 4 characters long and your first argument is 3, it is working as expected. If you try `firstName.PadLeft(6, '*')` you'll get **Mary.

Answer (score 6):

You should add length of your string like that:

```
firstName = firstName.PadLeft(firstName.Length + 3, '*');
```

First parameter(totalWidth) represents the result string length. If your string length is less then totalWidth parameter, PadLeft adds so many chars that result string length will be equal to totalWidth.

Answer (score 3):

No, it works. It will pad on the left with the supplied character to a total string length of 3. So, if you wanted a result of `***Mary`, you would have to use `firstName.PadLeft(7, '*');`

Comment: Sorry, the above isn't entirely correct, but that's only because SO seems to like removing * characters from my posts, but I think you get the gist of it.

Comment: In addition, if you're simply adding a static amount of characters to the start of a string, simply use firstName = "***" + firstName

Comment: How about padding like this: " ".PadLeft(23)+firstName;

Answer (score 2):

3 is the total length of the string so if your string is "a", it will become "**a"

see [String.PadLeft Method (Int32, Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)